# Footer Issue - Local and header differ only on one page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am a having a footer issue where my production on one page doesn't match the rest of the content of the website.  When I run it locally it looks fine but on production this page is the only page that is being wrapped by a div wrapper.  For example

Locally:

[image]
[image]

On Production:
[image]
[image]

I checked the HTML (locally) to see if I was wrapping the wrong way but I just don't see it.  All the other pages on the site are not wrapped in this way.  Could there be something with the asset pipeline that could be causing this difference between local vs production?

Comment: Could be some include not loading.  Try using IE F12 tools or firefox firebug and click on the item to see what style is being used.

Comment: Use the DOM Inspector and see if all the stylesheets are being loaded using the network tab

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a style sheet issue?  I updated the post with images but it seems like on production the footer is wrapped but not locally.

Comment: I would validate your HTML markup on production and make sure everything has proper closing tags (or there aren't any stray closing tags) and is nested properly

Comment: could you give us the url so we can inspect it?

Comment: @zgood how exactly would i go about doing this process? Is it something on rails or a 3rd party site?

Comment: If you want you could use the W3C validation service [here](https://validator.w3.org/), but I was meaning validating it yourself by looking over the markup in question

Comment: @zgood I added a ending div since W3C validation said I was missing a div tag (which i don't see) and it works.  I think it has something to do with one of my contents being dynamically generated and causing the closing tags to not work.  If you submit as answer I will approve.  I'm going to dive even further to see what is causing this!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue was being caused because one of the `<div>`'s was missing a closing tag and elements weren't being wrapped properly in the production environment.

You can use the [W3C validation service](https://validator.w3.org/) to validate your markup to try and catch any invalid markup.